# Understanding this go back logic

Tags: javascript, logic

I saw this go back code in a website and I am trying to use it on my website. I am having trouble in understanding how the toURl and refUrl are being generated in it. Please guide about their structure. Thanks

```
var backtriggered = false;
setTimeout('goBack()',timer);

function goBack() {
  if(backtriggered) return false;
  backtriggered = true;
  toURL=getWelcomeCookie('toURL');
  refURL = getWelcomeCookie('refURL');
  var reg = /(.*)\/sites\/(.*)\/(\d{4})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(.*)\/?/;

  if(reg.test(toURL) == false){ 
    document.cookie="toURL"+ "=" +escape(toURL)+";path=/; domain=.mycsnippets.com; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1900 00:00:01 GMT";
    document.cookie="refURL"+ "=" +escape(toURL)+";path=/; domain=.mycsnippets.com; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1900 00:00:01 GMT";
 }
  location.href=toURL;
}
```

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: What does  document.cookie="toURL"+ "=" +escape(toURL)+";path=/; domain=.mycsnippets.com; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1900 00:00:01 GMT";
 do?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.cookie="toURL"+ "=" +escape(toURL)+";path=/; domain=.mycsnippets.com; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1900 00:00:01 GMT";
```

This line puts a value in the brower's cookie store. For more information I think you should read this first: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to set cookies: through server response, and through javascript.

What this code does is set cookies using javascript which say where the visitor has been and where he is going before setting the url to the target url (toURL).  This way next page when it is called it knows to go back to the url which was set in the cookies as the previous url.